# c++ Boost library 1.63.0 or 1.64.0 not working on visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

when I am trying to  Install Boost. Build on Visual studio 2015 using (using vc14' toolset).
Getting following error when I am executing bootstrap.bat file.

Bootstrap.log file Error :

#### Using 'vc14' toolset.

```
F:\SunGard_04022016\code\boost\boost_1_63_0\tools\build\src\engine>if exist bootstrap rd /S /Q bootstrap 
F:\SunGard_04022016\code\boost\boost_1_63_0\tools\build\src\engine>md bootstrap 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\malloc.h(104): error C2054: expected '(' to follow '_CRTNOALIAS'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\malloc.h(104): error C2085: 'calloc': not in formal parameter list
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\malloc.h(105): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_CRTNOALIAS'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\malloc.h(106): error C2054: expected '(' to follow '_CRTNOALIAS'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\malloc.h(106): error C2085: 'malloc': not in formal parameter list
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\malloc.h(108): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_CRTNOALIAS'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\malloc.h(110): error C2054: expected '(' to follow '_CRTNOALIAS'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(309): error C2085: 'scanf_s': not in formal parameter list
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(311): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(318): error C2054: expected '(' to follow '_CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(318): error C2085: '_snprintf_s': not in formal parameter list
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(321): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(330): error C2054: expected '(' to follow '_CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(330): error C2085: 'sscanf_s': not in formal parameter list
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(332): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(335): error C2054: expected '(' to follow '_CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(335): error C2085: '_snscanf_s': not in formal parameter list
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(336): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(359): error C2054: expected '(' to follow '_CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(359): error C2085: '_vsnprintf_s': not in formal parameter list
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(362): warning C4081: expected ')'; found 'string'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(363): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro '__DEFINE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NFUNC_0_2_ARGLIST_EX'
......
```

Does anyone know how to fix/work around this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It'll take less time to simply install Linux from scratch, and get both a modern C++ compiler and all common libraries, like Boost, ready to go. Last time I did this it took me less than an hour and a half to install Linux on a new machine.

Comment: I have compiled boost with msvc hundreds of times at work but I have not done so with VC2015 in many years. Can't you update to a newer version? I will understand if you can't. I am stuck on 2019 at the moment because upgrading to 2022 will require me to purchase a new license of an extension which I use all the time.